# How to add a dynamic user group to an azure ad enterprise app with terraform

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform

I am trying to add a dynamic user group to my Azure AD Enterprise Application. I followed the steps outlined in the documentation, but nothing happened after setting up the `app_roles`.

Since Sep 2, 2021 Terraform added the Dynamic group Support:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/132#issuecomment-911843531

Resource: azuread_application — Documentation:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application

Based on my understanding of the documentation, the only method to assign roles to the app is through the app_role functionality. My first attempt was to add the Object Group ID and set the `allowed_member_types` to `Users`.

```
resource "azuread_application" "test-app" {
  display_name = "test-app"
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User"]
    description          = "Reader"
    display_name         = "Reader"
    enabled              = true
    id = "#####-####-####-####-######" <- Group Object ID
    value = "Reader"
  }
  
  web {
    logout_url    = var.logout_url
    redirect_uris = var.redirect_uris

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }
}
```

However, this approach did not produce the desired result, as the group did not appear in the Enterprise Application. It's possible that there is a misunderstanding on my part regarding this process.

We could have also the group_membership_claims:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application#group_membership_claims

I am finding the documentation challenging to understand, despite my efforts to follow it closely.

Any assistance or further clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that:

1. Following permissions like `Group.ReadWrite.All` or
   `Directory.ReadWrite.All` are required to perform actions on groups.
2. If using the `assignable_to_role` property, this resource additionally
   requires one of the following application roles:
   `RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory` or Directory.ReadWrite.All

> assignable_to_role which is (Optional) Indicates whether this group
> can be assigned to an Azure Active Directory role. Can only be true
> for ***security-enabled groups.***
>
> Check if security enable is true and dynamic membership rule are
> given: **[Group with dynamic membership](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/group)**.

See in section [**Assign a user and group to an internal application**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/app_role_assignment#example-usage)
Also check the version as this functionality has been ***released in v2.13.0*** of the Terraform Provider.

When authenticated with a `service principal`, this resource requires one of the following application roles: `AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All` and `Application.Read.Al`l, or ( AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All and Directory.Read.All ), or Application.ReadWrite.All, or Directory.ReadWrite.All

Here try by including ***`allowed_member_types = ["Application", "User"]`***,   **`security_enabled = true`** for the azure ad group and ***`app_role_assignment_required = true`***

```
data "azuread_domains" "example" {
  only_initial = true
}

resource "azuread_application" "internal" {
  display_name = "internal"

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["Application", "User"]
    description          = "Admins can perform all task actions"
    display_name         = "Admin"
    enabled              = true
    id                   = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-222222222222"
    value                = "Admin.All"
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "internal" {
  application_id = azuread_application.internal.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = true
}

resource "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "example"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "example" {
  app_role_id         = azuread_service_principal.internal.app_role_ids["Admin.All"]
  principal_object_id = azuread_group.example.object_id
  resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.internal.object_id
}
```

Check if you can try using [rest api endpoint](https://using%20rest%20api%20endpoint)